# iptables DROP policy on INPUT causing 10+s of latency in SQL responses

Tags: debian, iptables, mysql, firewall

I am trying to lock down my db server but have encountered something I cannot explain.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 source IP range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.42          0.0.0.0/0
```

The above is producing 10+ seconds of latency for all SQL queries from the webserver at 192.168.1.42. The chain below does not.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 source IP range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.42          0.0.0.0/0
3    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Do these chains not essentially do the same thing? Why is a DROP policy causing so much delay?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that MySQL was trying to do reverse DNS lookups. I set the option 'skip-name-resolve' in the MySQL config file, and this appears to have resolved the issue.

Comment: While I'm pleased that you've resolved your own issue, your two `iptables` blocks are essentially the same, so you should have had the same DNS lookups problem with either.

Comment: @roaima most likely the 2nd case included an interface restriction. Without using the -v option, iptables -L (used by OP) doesn't display interfaces, which gives an useless result.